# C# Convert DateTime to String result in Server Error

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

It is a very simple code, and I have no idea why it has problem.

```
DateTime temp = DateTime.Now;
s = temp.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

The code above will work. But it will shows Server Error in '/' Application if I change the yyyyMMdd to yyyy-MM-dd, or yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:tt, or any other form even just ToString().

Is there a way to fix it? I want to show something like 2012-9-6 10:17:31.

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem happens because you are using the resultant string in a context where dashes are not allowed.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the actual error.

Comment: OK... I fixed it lol it's due to I copy the String s to the wrong field of Table type of int... -.-" late night lol

Answer (score 0):

What about trying

```
s = String.Format("{0:yyyy/M/d HH:mm:ss}", temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a default culture that affects the formatting.

Try with the invariant culture:

```
s = temp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```